# Making a editable form in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

How can I design a editable form as in detail of a person by clicking edit button and edit the respective fields of person's details and save it on the same place where they are shown.

**eg.**

```
Full Name : JTextField1
Address: JTextField2
and so on...
```

Now What I want is to save those values on respective places and when I want to edit them then show editable textfield with same values displayed.
Are there any *API's or plugins* to do it or should I just have to do as `setVisible(true/false)` for necessary action to perform??

Comment: even if there is api that will do the same setVisible true/false in that code..Have you tried binding

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JavaFX, you can use setEditable(boolean), which will disable or enable the field for editing. You can also use setDisabled(boolean) to disable the field for anything other than viewing.

If you are using Swing/AWT, you can use setEditable(boolean) as well as setEnabled(boolean) to do the same as JavaFX.

Since you are using Swing/Awt, use setEditable to disable or enable the fields when you press the Edit button. :)

Comment: This does help but I meant for more professional typo. This keeps showing the JTextFields. I don't want text fields to be seen when we save but only when we need editing. :) I hope you understand what I want. Thanks though

Comment: In that case, you should have two panels/panes, one for editing and one for viewing. The editing pane would contain editable textfields, and the viewing pane would contain labels.

The information would be received from a separate class so that both labels and textfields can retrieve the values.